# Authenticate Azure Dev Ops services client library with Client Id and Secret

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, sdk

I am looking to build a custom front end application to facilitate release management.  I want to integrate with Azure Dev Ops using the client libraries.

Is there a non-interactive way of authenticating other than a PAT that will expire?  I don't want to use delegated access because I will control the permissions from the app.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I guess it answers the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a non-interactive way of authenticating other than a PAT that will expire?

AFAIK, I am afraid there is no such a non-interactive way of authenticating except PAT.

There is [a similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1636) on github:

> All the authentication method for accessing Azure Devops service is
>   interactive except one(which still needs interaction through user
>   specific device like mobile).
>
> There is no good way to do auth towards the devops api for a
>   non-interactive service. They all require user interaction or a fake

And you could vote and comment the user voice [Support for non-interactive service access via service principals.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/696523/support-for-non-interactive-service-access-via-ser.html).

As workaround, you could use a PAT, and extend its period to one year.

Hope this helps.

> user service account or similar.